# How to run any application from one machine to another in network using python

Tags: python, wmi

i want to run any application from one computer to another using Command Prompt or python script. connection is established with other computer using WMI python library but unable to run application

```
try:
    connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password)
    process_startup = connection.Win32_ProcessStartup.new()
    process_startup.ShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL
    process_id, result = connection.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine="notepad.exe path.txt", ProcessStartupInformation=process_startup)
except wmi.x_wmi:
    print ("Your Username and Password of "+getfqdn(ip)+" are wrong.")
```

Answer (score 0):

RPyC (pronounced like are-pie-see), or Remote Python Call, is a transparent library for symmetrical remote procedure calls, clustering, and distributed-computing. RPyC makes use of object-proxying, a technique that employs python's dynamic nature, to overcome the physical boundaries between processes and computers, so that remote objects can be manipulated as if they were local. 
 https://github.com/tomerfiliba/rpyc